# Windows 10 black screen with blinking cursor - cannot boot

Tags: windows-10

I cannot start my Windows machine. I get a black screen and a blinking white cursor. It is not responsive.

What happened was I was using the PC but the machine was running very slow, and then became completely unresponsive. I hard powered off the machine. When I restarted it, I got the Windows loading dots going round in a circle for some time. I then hard powered off the machine again. Upon restart, I experienced the symptoms above.

I believe that perhaps Windows was doing an upgrade and got interrupted.

I have tried the following trouble shooting steps:

I created a Windows bootable installation USB stick from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56485).

When I boot from the USB, I am presented with a screen asking

> It looks as if you started an upgrade and booted from installation
>   media. If you want to continue with the upgrade, remove the media from
>   your PC and click yes. If you want to perform a clean installation
>   instead, click No.

If I click "yes", the machine reboots and takes me back to the black screen again.

If I click "No", it asks for my localisation preferences, which I specify and click "next".

I am then presented with a screen with two options

> Install Now
>   Repair your computer

I click "Repair your computer"

I am presented with a screen with two options

> Troubleshoot
>   Turn off your PC

I click on "Troubleshoot"

I get

> System Restore
>   Go back to previous version
>   System Image Recovery
>   Start-up repair
>   command prompt

I click "start up repair"

It shows "Diagnosing your PC", and then "start up repair couldn't repair your PC"

I click "System restore" – I get

> To use system restore, you must specify which Windows installation to restore. Restart this computer, select an operating system, and then select System restore.

I click "Go back to the previous version", and I get

> We ran into a problem and won't be able to go back tot the previous version of windows. Try resetting your PC instead *Troubleshoot > Reset the PC"

I click on "System Image Recovery", but I don't have a system image to recover from.

I click on "Command Prompt". Following advice found elsewhere on the Internet, I try the `bootrec` command:

```
bootrec /RebuildBcd
```

I get

> Successfully scanned Windows installations.
>   Total identified Windows installations: 1
>   C:\Windows
>   Add installation to boot list? Yes etc

I enter "Y"

I get

> Element not found

I enter

```
bootrec /fixMbr
```

I get

> The operation completed sucessfully

I enter

```
bootrec /fixboot
```

I get

> Element not found

I reboot the system without the USB stick. Same black screen with blinking cursor. I boot using the USB stick again, and go back to the command prompt.

I enter

```
bootsect /nt60 ALL
```

It states

```
C: \\?\volume{00030698-0000-0000-0000-100000000000}
Successfully updated NTFS filesystem bootcode
```

I reboot and get the black screen again.

I Reboot with the USB and go to the command prompt again. I enter

```
bcdboot C:\windows /s M:
```

It gives

> Failure when initialising library system volume

You may note the the /s option is specifying a volume called "M". I don't have that volume.

I use disk part like this:

```
Diskpart
list volumes
```

It shows 3 drives that I use as storage drives, the USB stick, and the C drive which is where Windows is installed. I think that perhaps my Windows installation is using this volume as the system partition and the boot partition. So I tried

```
bcdboot c:\windows /s c
```

I get

```
BFSVC Error: Failed to set element application device. Status = [c00000bb]
BFSVC Error: Failed to populate BCD store. Status = [c00000bb]
```

I check that the C volume is active

```
DiskPart
select volume 2
detail volume
```

I get

```
Partition 1
Type   : 07
Hidden   : No 
Active   : Yes 
Offset in bytes : 1048576
```

I check the that other volumes are not active. They are not except for the USB stick.

I try

```
bootsect /nt60 N: /force /mbr 
attrib -s -h C:\boot\bcd
ren C:\boot\bcd bcd.old
bcdboot c:\windows /s c:
```

I get

> Boot files successfully created

I try rebooting. Same black screen. FFS. I go back to the command prompt as above.

I try

```
bootrec /scanos
```

I get

> Successfully scanned windows installations
>   Total identified Windows installations: 1
>   [1] C:\Windows
>   The operation completed successfully

I try

```
bcdedit /export c:\BCD_Backup
```

I get

> The store operation has failed.
>   The requested system device cannot be found

At this point I try rebooting the system and get the same black screen.

I have now run out of ideas and things to try. Does anyone have something I can try?

Comment: Its hosed, back up data and reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an option for Startup settings?
[startup Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLrD3.png)

If so you may be able to get into safe mode
from there you will be able to update drivers and turn off services etc..

Comment: No I do not unfortunately

Comment: If you're currently booting from a usb take out the usb and try boot up normally if you get circles spinning forever try the graphics card option.


**Graphics Card**
If it has a graphics card take it out and plug your cable into your on-board graphics and try boot it up.

**System Restore**
In your system restore it cant find you? maybe your Hard drive is dying