# xcopy fails with insufficient memory error

Tags: windows-10

I am trying to create a backup of my c drive to another drive using a windows bootable USB stick and in troubleshooting mode.

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1323350/windows-10-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor-cannot-boot) as to why I am doing this

I can't install other software (I don't think). I ran the command:

`c:\*.* d:\cBackup\ /e /f /h /k /j /c`

and got

> Insufficient memory
>   305157 Files copied

I notice that there is no Windows folder in the destination.

Does that mean that it copied everything that it could, and had some paths that were too long? Or that it failed the first time it had a path that was too long?

What other options do I have for making this backup?

Comment: You could use a Linux Live Boot disc: an individual file copy will not copy all the attributes, since Linux does not know about Hidden and System properties, but a partition copy will create a faithful copy. Alternatively, a diagnostic disc like [Hiren's Boot CD](https://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) will allow you to use Explorer for the copy, though it is some years old now, and may not be up-to-date with the most recent file system enhancements.

Comment: Use `Robocopy` command instead of `xcopy`.

Comment: There are a number of other boot options described [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/the-ultimate-pc-repair-toolkit-in-your-pocket-ultimate-boot-cd-on-a-usb-stick/).

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used robocopy

Note that, robocopy has some odd defaults. If it can't copy a file, it will retry in 30s, up to 1,000,000 times...

So I set those options to 1 sec and 5 times.