# Black Screen with Blinking Cursor while Booting

Tags: windows-10

So I tried to solve this problem with Ctrl+Alt+Dlt and Ctrl+Alt+Esc but it doesn't budge. My computer doesn't have a password. Help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 black screen with blinking cursor - cannot boot](https://superuser.com/questions/1323350/windows-10-black-screen-with-blinking-cursor-cannot-boot)

Comment: This is almost always grahics driver related... if you can boot in Safe Mode, it's the graphics driver... uninstall the current one and allow Windows update to reinstall.  If same issue occurs again, boot up Safe Mode with networking, download the prior driver version, then uninstall the current driver, this time also selecting to "_delete the driver software for this device_".  Disconnect from network, reboot into Windows, ensuring you are not connected via ethernet/wifi, and install the prior driver version you downloaded.